# Why is my code not executed, is it unreachable?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, java

Here `Sytem.out.println()` showing an error why?

```
int c=1;
for(int i=1;1>0;i++)
{
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Next']")).click();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    c=c+1;
}
System.out.println(c);
```

Comment: What do you intend the code to do? Your loop condition is always true so, by definition, you have an infinite loop and it won't even get to the print statement. More likely the error you're seeing is due to integer overflow.

Comment: thank you@FDM    i got it. but my doubt is, i have written a code for NEXT ELEMENT in the for loop block, BUT after some executions there won't be next element in that page . then is for loop  not terminated itself ?? and doesn't it print C value?

Comment: Your loop condition (1>0) doesn't depend in any way on the result of the findelement call. Your loop will run until something throws an exception, and then since the print is outside of the loop, it won't be called.

Comment: Thanks@FDM started learning a few days ago so that getting very small doubts. thanks for your information.

Comment: Is it really the print showing an error? Can you tell us the exact error, maybe with a screenshot?

Comment: Voting to close this question as it is a programming question and not specific to testing. Better asked on stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1):

Because you have an infinite loop that will throw an exception when the element is not found anymore. If the program gets an exception (e.g. ElementNotFound) then it breaks all computation. So it never reaches the code outside of the for-loop.

```
int c = 1;
boolean error = false;
while(!error) {
    try {
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Next']")).click();
      c++;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      // if we get here we have an exception
      error = true
    }
 }
 System.out.println(c);
```

You can use a try/catch block to catch any error and handle it or quit a loop like in the example above. Not 100% sure the syntax is correct, haven't written any Java in 6 years, but read it as pseudo code and fix where needed :)

Comment: Though the answer is correct, the exception is from `Thread.sleep` which is `InterruptedException`. `ElementNotFound` is an RuntimeException :)

Comment: @DakshinamurthyKarra Why would `Thread.sleep` throw an exception? It is the `driver.findElement()` that probably throws the exception. Think you are confusing something.

Comment: Not at runtime. At the compile time, `Thread.sleep` throws a marked exception `InterruptedException` that we must catch in the code. `findElement` throws a exception that is derived from `WebDriverException` that itself is derived from `RuntmeException` so it is unmarked. We do not need to catch it in the code.

Comment: I don't think the original question was about compile time exceptions, but we will never know because the question was very badly asked :)